# AngularJS TypeError: $resource is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have the following controller that is giving me trouble in the form of

> TypeError: $resource is not a function

pointing to `var Activities = $resource('/api/activities');`

```
app.controller('AddActivityCtrl',['$scope','$resource','$location','$rootScope',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $resource, $location){
        console.log($scope.user.email);
        //$scope.activity.user = $rootScope.user.email;
        $scope.save = function(){
            var Activities = $resource('/api/activities');
            $scope.activity.events = [];
            Activities.save($scope.activity, function(){
                $location.path('/')
            })
        }
    }
]);
```

It used to work well, but I just tested this feature and something I have done since I last tested it seems to have broken it. What could be the cause of this?

The following comes from app.js

```
var activities = require('./routes/activities');
app.use('/api/activities', activities);
```

And in my activities.js I have

```
//API point for listing all existing activities
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    var collection = db.get('Activity');
    //collection.find({}, function(err, activities){
    collection.find({user:req.user.email}, function(err, activities){
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(activities);
    });
});

...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be with order of injection

```
app.controller('AddActivityCtrl',['$scope','$resource','$location','$rootScope',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $resource, $location){
```

You are injecting `$resource` as second service but passing `$rootScope` as second parameter.

Order of injection and arguments must match

```
['$scope','$resource','$location','$rootScope',
        function($scope, $resource, $location, $rootScope){..}
```

Comment: I didn't know this. Is this true for all parameters?

Comment: This is what I read from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

When using this type of annotation, take care to keep the annotation array in sync with the parameters in the function declaration.